# How to invoke base-class method of injected object?

Tags: c#, reflection, dependency-injection, interface, invoke

(*I couldn't come up with a succinct title for this question that didn't drag on.*)

I have a base class that has one public method:

```
public class MyBaseClass
{
    public void MyBaseMethod()
    {
        // Here is where the functionality will go, that is described below.
    }
}
```

I have another class, derived from my base class, that contains injected objects that also derive from `MyBaseClass`:

```
public class MyWorkingClass : MyBaseClass
{
    // All of these objects also derive from MyBaseClass.
    private readonly IClassOne _classOne;
    private readonly IClassTwo _classTwo;
    private readonly IClassThree _classThree;

    public MyWorkingClass(
        IClassOne classOne,
        IClassTwo classTwo,
        IClassThree classThree)
    {
        _classOne = classOne;
        _classTwo = classTwo;
        _classThree = classThree;
    }

    public SomeMethod()
    {
        // Stuff goes here.

        // Call base method here.
        MyBaseMethod();
    }
}
```

What I want to happen is that the call to `MyBaseMethod` will collect all of the fields declared in the class. For each field, get its instance and call its own `MyBaseMethod`.

I can get all of the fields in a class instance:

```
var fields = GetType()
    .GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
    .ToList();
```

For each field in the list, I can get its field type, instance and its own declared methods:

```
foreach (var field in fields)
{
    var fieldType = field.FieldType;

    var fieldInstance = field
        .GetValue(this);

    var methods = fieldType
        .GetMethods();
}
```

My problem is that my base-class method, `MyBaseMethod`, is not included in the list of methods.
I have also tried `GetRuntimeMethods()`, but it is not included there either.

If I could get access to the base-class method, then I could invoke it:

```
var methodInfo = fieldType
    .GetMethod('MyBaseMethod');

methodInfo
    .Invoke(fieldInstance, null);
```

**Question:** How can I manage to invoke my base-class method in each field instance, given that its type is listed as being an interface?

Thanks.

Comment: It is very confusing why you expect `MyBaseMethod` to be available on on of the IClassXxx interfaces... Some [edit] showing at least on of those interfaces could help... Your reasoning why `MyBaseMethod` should be present on the interface could help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem here, is you need to use the actual *instance* from the `field`

**E.g**

```
var methods = fieldInstance
    .GetType()
    .GetRuntimeMethods();
```

---

**Example**

Given some contrived set of classes and interfaces (trying to replicate what you have described)

```
public interface ITest { }

public class SomeOtherClass : MyBaseClass, ITest { }

public class MyWorkingClass : MyBaseClass, ITest
{
   private readonly ITest _test;

   public MyWorkingClass(ITest test)
   {
      _test = test;
   }

   public void SomeMethod()
   {    
      MyBaseMethod(); 
   }
}

public class MyBaseClass
{
   public void MyBaseMethod()
   {
      var fields = GetType()
         .GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
         .ToList();

      foreach (var field in fields)
      {
         var fieldType = field.FieldType;

         var fieldInstance = field
            .GetValue(this);

         if (fieldInstance == null)
            return;
         var methods = fieldInstance
            .GetType()
            .GetRuntimeMethods();

         foreach (var item in methods)
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);

      }  
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var asd = new MyWorkingClass(new SomeOtherClass());
asd.SomeMethod();
```

**Output**

```
MyBaseMethod
GetType
MemberwiseClone
Finalize
ToString
Equals
GetHashCode
```

[**The words most convoluted example**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UPQjVR)